# Equivalent of md5(uniqid(mt_rand())) in as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

What is the equivalent of `md5(uniqid(mt_rand()))` in actionscript 3.0?

Comment: Hey, no, you don't wanna use this! As it seems you're trying to generate random numbers. However your method (in PHP) is cryptographically insecure and the numbers are easily predictable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the md5 library from [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib), you'll want a guid library like this one at [rgbeffects](http://www.rgbeffects.com/blog/actionscript/actionscript-3-guid-%E2%80%93-generating-unique-ids-for-users-in-as3/)

```
import com.adobe.crypto.MD5;
import com.rgbeffects.GUID;

var hash:String = MD5.hash(GUID.create());
```

Answer (score 3):

ActionScript doesn't have an md5 encryption method for whatever reason. However you can find several AS libraries that include md5. Try [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) for starters.